# Extend Libeasy to support chromecast

Tags: android, encryption, mp4, chromecast

We are using Libeasy to decrypt our videos and play them using android Mediaplayer , which works fine . Now we want to use the Libeasy http server to stream the local content to chromecast. 
The server listens on localhost because of which it could not get the stream on chromecast. 
Has anyone tried LocalSingleHttpServer extending it? Is there any other library which will address both use cases (decryption and chromecast).

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The Chromecast support has been added in the version 3 of Libeasy.